# calloc() function instead of malloc()

Tags: c, malloc, calloc

I want to change `malloc()` function to `calloc()`, but I am confused: how I can do it in this piece of code?

```
void *mymalloc(size_t len)
{

    void *buf;
    size_t pages = (len & PAGE_MASK) + 2;
    size_t offset = PAGE_SIZE - (len & ~PAGE_MASK);

    if(offset < sizeof(size_t))
    {
        pages++;
        offset += PAGE_SIZE;
    }

    if((buf = mmap(NULL, pages << PAGE_SHIFT, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, 
                    MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0, 0)) == -1)
    {
        perror("mymalloc/mmap");
        exit(1);
    }
    *(size_t *)buf = len;
    *(size_t *)(buf+offset+len) = len;

    if(mprotect(buf+offset+len, PAGE_SIZE, PROT_NONE) == -1)
    {
        perror("mymalloc/mprotect");
        exit(1);
    }

    return buf+offset;
}
```

Comment: There is no `malloc()` in your code now.  What are you asking?

Comment: There is no `malloc()` there; there's just a `mymalloc()`.  Presumably, you want a `mycalloc()` that calls `mymalloc()` and then zeroes the space.  You also have to account for `malloc()` taking one argument and `calloc()` taking two that have to be multiplied to produce the requested size.

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mmap.html the very FIRST google result

Answer (score 2):

`calloc()` is effectively just `malloc()` with a `memset()` to zero.

Assuming you want a `mycalloc()` to supplement your `mymalloc()`:

```
void *mymalloc( size_t bytes )
{
    ...
    return( ptr );
}
```

you'd get:

```
void *mycalloc( size_t bytes, size_t n )
{
    size_t total_bytes = bytes * n;
    void *ptr = mymalloc( total_bytes );
    memset( ptr, 0, total_bytes );
    return( ptr );
}
```

You'll want to add checks for multiplication overflow and NULL returns from `mymalloc()`.

Comment: You are forgetting to make sure that the multiplication does not overflow.

Comment: @Deduplicator I want to leave *something* for the OP to figure out...  [And no, I wasn't forgetting.  ;-)]

Comment: If your target environment is Linux, you don't even need the memset, MAP_ANONYMOUS pages come zerod.

Comment: @JohnHascall True.  That does make the `mycalloc()` implementation dependent upon `mymalloc()` returning zeroed memory though.

Comment: Yes, my comment was mostly an aside.  if you really wanted to do this you would best surround the `memset` with a feature test macro, something like `#ifndef _HAVE_ZEROING_ANON_MMAP`

Answer (score 0):

When you have questions like this, always check manual pages:

- Malloc:

> `void *malloc(size_t size);` The  malloc() function allocates size bytes and returns a pointer to
>   the allocated memory.  The memory is not initialized.  If size is 0,
>   then malloc() returns either NULL, or a unique pointer value that can
>   later be successfully passed to free().

- Calloc:

> `void *calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size);` The calloc() function
>   allocates memory for an array of nmemb elements of size bytes each and
>   returns a pointer  to  the  allocated memory.  The memory is set to
>   zero.  If nmemb or size is 0, then calloc() returns either NULL, or a
>   unique pointer value that can later be successfully passed to free().

Difference is that calloc also initialize allocated block of memory to zeroes.

Comment: Note: A second difference, not seen much today, is that `calloc()` could handle allocations like `calloc(SIZE_MAX/8, 16)` whereas `malloc()` cannot.  Useful on segmented architectures.